# Permalink structure between 2 custom post types and a taxonomy

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type called *Communities*, a custom post type called *Community Posts*, and a taxonomy under *Community Posts* called *Communities*.

The idea here is that whenever a new *Community* is added, a taxonomy term is generated matching that name (if it doesn't exist already). So the user can now write blog posts under the *Community Posts* post type and categorize it under the taxonomy term for that city.

Here is how the client needs the permalink structure:

Cities post type:

```
example.com/community/{community-name}
```

A single City Post categorized under the matching city name taxonomy:

```
example.com/community/{community-name}/{article-about-community}
```

Right now I have the following code in place:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_city' );
function register_post_type_city() {

    $menu_name = 'Communities';
    $regular_name = 'Communities';
    $singular_name = 'Community';
    $register_name = 'city';
    $icon = 'dashicons-location-alt';

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( $regular_name, 'post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( $singular_name, 'post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( $menu_name, 'admin menu', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( $singular_name, 'add new on admin bar', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', $register_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All ' . $regular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search ' . $regular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent ' . $regular_name . ':', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No ' . $regular_name . ' found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No ' . $regular_name . ' found in Trash.', 'textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 
            'slug' => 'community',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => 'community',
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon'          => $icon,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail'  )
    );
    register_post_type( $register_name, $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_city_post_taxonomy', 0 );
function register_city_post_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'communities', 
        'city_post', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => 'Communities',   
                'singular_name' => 'Community News',    
                'search_items'  => 'Search Communities',    
                'edit_item'     => 'Edit Community',    
                'add_new_item'  => 'Add New Community'
            ),  
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,    
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'community/communities', 
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_city_post' );
function register_post_type_city_post() {

    $menu_name = 'Community Posts';
    $regular_name = 'Community Posts';
    $singular_name = 'Community Post';
    $register_name = 'city_post';
    $icon = 'dashicons-format-status';

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( $regular_name, 'post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( $singular_name, 'post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( $menu_name, 'admin menu', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( $singular_name, 'add new on admin bar', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', $register_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View ' . $singular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All ' . $regular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search ' . $regular_name, 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent ' . $regular_name . ':', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No ' . $regular_name . ' found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No ' . $regular_name . ' found in Trash.', 'textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 
            'slug' => 'community/%communities%',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon'          => $icon,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail'  )
    );
    register_post_type( $register_name, $args );
}

add_filter('post_link', 'community_posts_type_permalink', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'community_posts_type_permalink', 1, 3);

function community_posts_type_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%communities%' ) === FALSE || 'city_post' != get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return $permalink; 
    }

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'communities' );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    } else {
        $taxonomy_slug = 'no-community';
    }

    return str_replace( '%communities%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
```

Everything is working great except that I am getting 404 errors on the single Community Post pages. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you refreshed the permalinks? [See this explanation.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules)

Comment: Yes @Linnea I have

Comment: Well, I'm afraid, it won't work like this, because the way WP processes RewritrRules. It scans them in order and matches first one. So if cities is hierarchical, then any URL like community/x/y/z is matched as city structure.  Why are you using 2 CPTs for this? Why not only one CPT and one taxonomy?